# Why does Guava's TypeToken<T>.getRawType() return Class<? super T> instead of Class<T>

Tags: java, generics, guava

From Effective Java Second Edition, Item 28 : "Do not use wildcard types as return types. Rather than providing additional flexibility for your users it would force them to use wildcard types in client code."

```
public final Class<? super T> getRawType()
```

I've just been getting to grips with generic wildcards to understand the last unchecked cast warning I have in a piece of code I am writing and I don't understand why getRawType() returns a wildcard type.

```
class Base<T>{}
class Child<T> extends Base<T>{}

public <C> void test (TypeToken<? extends Base<C>> token) {
    Class<? extends Base<C>> rawType = (Class<? extends Base<C>>) token.getRawType();
}
```

I have to cast token.getRawType() as it returns a

```
Class<? super ? extends Base<C>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What if you have a `TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>` and you want to get `Class<ArrayList>` (that *is* the raw type). If it returned `Class<T>`, then it would return `Class<ArrayList<String>>` which is not `Class<ArrayList>` that you want.

Comment: Thanks @newacct, this is the thing I didn't understand, but it makes sense that ArrayList<String> extends ArrayList. The Class<? super T> is descriptive of what it's returning although as far as the client code is concerned it may as well return Class<?>, as you'll always have to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

If the generic type of "token" is a Type class (i.e. if S in

```
TypeToken<S>
```

is a java.lang.reflect.Type class), then TypeToken.getRawType() will return the raw type associated to S. It shall be a Class object, parent of S.

See the source code of [TypeToken](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java?r=2).

In some cases (like having multiple bounds), the strategy implemented won't work and having a raw type is Ok: the raw type will be Object.class

See for instance [MoreTypes](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/MoreTypes.java?r=dfee9fd5f78c5f1f769713b603e4e92a0b7b01e3):

```
public static Class<?> getRawType(Type type) {
...
} else if (type instanceof TypeVariable) {
  // we could use the variable's bounds, but that'll won't work if there are multiple.
  // having a raw type that's more general than necessary is okay  
  return Object.class;

} else {
...
}
```

Comment: I've read the source but still can't find a situation where a parent of S is returned. I tried `new TypeToken<WildcardType>(){}.getRawType()` but that returns a class of WildcardType, not any parent

Comment: Note that your `TypeToken` link points to the gson version. Here is the Guava version: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.java