# Guice: Why TypeLiteral<T> getRawType() method returns Class<? super T> instead of Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics, guice

I want to use Guice type literals built-in injection as I need to inject class information. See an example below:

```
public class Foo<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @Inject
    public Foo(TypeLiteral<T> literal) {
        this.clazz = literal.getRawType();
    }
}
```

It would have worked perfectly, but `getRawType()` method returns `Class<? super T>`. Internally `clazz` variable is being used as an argument of another class's method. 
If I modify `clazz` type to be `Class<? super T>` I would have to rework a bunch of classes.

What's the most elegant solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the raw type to the `Class<T>` in that case, though you might end up having it as unchecked, as follows:

```
@Inject
public Foo(TypeLiteral<T> literal) {
    this.clazz = (Class<T>) literal.getRawType();
}
```

To answer your question why it does so, there is similar answer to  [Why does Guava's TypeToken<T>.getRawType() return Class<? super T> instead of Class<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261476/why-does-guavas-typetokent-getrawtype-return-class-super-t-instead-of-cl). which has a very nice example as its answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can cast it, how safe is that? And why that method is not returning Class<T> instead?

Comment: @IhorM. updated the answer, ideally this should be a duplicate of the link shared. voting for that